# Why the XmlInclude does not work in my project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I override the Serialize for removing all the attribute prefix of XML:

Here is the startup.cs:

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                options.OutputFormatters.Add(new Classes.XmlSerializerOutputFormatterNamespace());
            })
```

And here is the code of override Serialize:

```
public class XmlSerializerOutputFormatterNamespace : XmlSerializerOutputFormatter

{
    protected override void Serialize(XmlSerializer xmlSerializer, XmlWriter xmlWriter, object value)
    {
        //applying "empty" namespace will produce no namespaces
        var emptyNamespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        emptyNamespaces.Add("", "any-non-empty-string");
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, value, emptyNamespaces);
    }
}
```

And here is the code of controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[Produces("application/xml")]
public async Task<BaseMsg> mp([FromBody]TextMsg XmlData)
{
    TextMsg ReturnXmlData = new TextMsg() { ToUserName = XmlData.FromUserName, FromUserName = XmlData.ToUserName ,CreateTime= XmlData.CreateTime, MsgType= "text", Content ="你好呀"};
    return ReturnXmlData;
}
[XmlInclude(typeof(BaseMsg))]
[XmlRoot("xml")]
public class BaseMsg {
    public string ToUserName { get; set; }
    public string FromUserName { get; set; }
    public string CreateTime { get; set; }
    public string MsgType { get; set; }
    public string MsgId { get; set; }
}
[XmlInclude(typeof(TextMsg))]
[XmlRoot("xml")]
public class TextMsg:BaseMsg {

    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

After I ran the program and send a post, Visual Studio reports an error in the override Serialize:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'There was an error generating the XML document.'

InvalidOperationException: The type Demo.Controllers.CallbackController+TextMsg was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically.
```

It seems reported this error for I did not use the XmlInclude. However, as you see I added it yet and why I did not work yet?

I found that if I don't inherit the BaseMsg class, it works without any error.

Would you please help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the attribute on your base message to this:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(TextMsg))]
```

and remove the `[XmlInclude(typeof(TextMsg))]` attribute from your text message

Comment: Well, it works. But now although I override the Serialize method, parent node of the XML will strangely append some strange attribute prefix: ' p1:type="TextMsg" xmlns:p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"'.  How can I remove this?

Answer (score 1):

In order to fix the exception see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58047753/7775908). While I don't know how to remove additional attributes during serialization I can suggest you an easy (but not very productive) workaround

```
public class XmlSerializerOutputFormatterNamespace : XmlSerializerOutputFormatter
{
    protected override void Serialize(XmlSerializer xmlSerializer, XmlWriter xmlWriter, object value)
    {
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(memoryStream, value);
        memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        //requires using System.Xml.Linq;
        XDocument document = XDocument.Load(memoryStream);
        document.Root.RemoveAttributes();
        document.WriteTo(xmlWriter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, it works. That's great!. However, I have to accept to another answer for it is relate to the question. Thanks all the same.